# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: filter. How to find this parameter?

Tags: c#, post, httprequest

[image]

I'm making a post request. 
The image above is the HTML response string running on a web browser control inside C#. This is just for better viewing.

This is the body:

> "username=user&useremail=email&userFullName=fullname&WesVersion=18116310&cid=410_EX03598&product=PROCESS&isModalPage=False&isBennerEnvironment=False&isProduction=True&environmentDescription=PRODU%c3%87%c3%83O&ActiveRole=role&canShowNPS=True&client=Banco&systemVersion=07.0"

This is the post:

```
var post = await req.Post(url, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
```

this is the function:

```
internal async Task<string> Post(string url, byte[] body)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
    webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, GetUriCookieContainer(new Uri(url)).GetCookieHeader(new Uri(url)));
    webRequest.CookieContainer = GetUriCookieContainer(new Uri(url));
    webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
    webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    webRequest.ContentLength = body.Length;
    webRequest.Referer = "url-referer";
    webRequest.Host = "url-host";

        using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(body, 0, body.Length);
        }
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return responseString;
}
```

The filter parameter does not appear for me in the browser network, either in the request body or in the header.

Comment: Seems like it's server-side error, not yours. Is resoruce you send responses to under your control?

Comment: Is this exception happening locally? or is it it the remote server returning this as an error message as a response (presumably in a 500-range error)? if the former: what is the stack trace? if the latter: maybe you are meant to *provide* a `filter` parameter? we don't know the API

Comment: @picolino I'm automating a search on a bank website and i have to make a post for this site.

Comment: Then you need to read this bank website API more detailed. Seems like resource you send requests to expecting `filter` parameter that you does not provide in your requests

Comment: It looks like a .NET exception. The question is whether the exception is thrown by _your_ code, or that this is the output from the bank's API?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm making a simulation of a post request that occurs when i click on a link of a bank website but i cant find the filter parameter in network tab. Either in the request body or in the header. 
This is not an API

Comment: this sounds like something you should talk to the site owner about; and if it isn't an API, you're on your own (and that is if you're not simply violating the ToS)

Comment: @picolino 
it's not an API, and like I said, I can't find the parameter in the request body or in the header.

Comment: @MarcGravell i agree

Comment: @CodeCaster its not an API, its the response from website after i made a post to bank's site.

Comment: Potato, tomato. Does your code throw this exception, or theirs?

Comment: _"i cant find the filter parameter in network tab"_ - that is because it's an ArgumentNullException, for a C# parameter. For all we know, this code passes the query string parameter `foo` or the cookie value `bar` to this method that accepts a `filter` parameter. We can't know this. What you're after, is rebuilding a POST request just as your browser would build it. Plenty of duplicate questions handle this subject.

Comment: @CodeCaster their code throws this exception. I'M rebuilding the post request like the site does